# Prototype Class.create not subclassing properly

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

So, I'm trying to extend a google maps class, specifically google.maps.OverlayView (in v3).  Doing it the vanilla js way totally works.

```
POIOverlay = function(marker, poi, type)
    {
        this._marker = marker;
        this._poi = poi;
        this._type = type;
        this._div = null;
        this.latlng_ = marker.getPosition();
        this._map = marker.getMap();
        this._offsetVertical = -195;
        this._offsetHorizontal = 0;
        this._height = 165;
        this._width = 266;
    }
    POIOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    POIOverlay.prototype.create = function()
    {
       console.log(this)
    }
    POIOverlay.prototype.draw = function()
    {
        //stuff
    }
```

However, doing it the prototype way, fails to add any of the parent class methods:

```
POIOverlay = Class.create(new google.maps.OverlayView(), {
    initialize : function(marker, poi, type)
    {
        this._marker = marker;
        this._poi = poi;
        this._type = type;
        this._div = null;
        this.latlng_ = marker.getPosition();
        this._map = marker.getMap();
        this._offsetVertical = -195;
        this._offsetHorizontal = 0;
        this._height = 165;
        this._width = 266;
    },
    create : function()
    {
        if(this._div) return;
        console.log(this);
    },
    draw : function()
    {
        //stuff
    }  
});
```

Here is the code to instantiate/use the class:

```
    try
    {
        poio = new POIOverlay(marker,poi,type);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e);
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
        poio.draw.bind(poio)
    );
```

In the first example, the console logs an object with the parent and child methods/attributes.  In the second example, the console logs an object with no parent attributes/methods.

Obviously, this is not too big of a deal, but I was wondering in anyone else has run into this issue and if it is easily corrected.  I am using prototype 1.7.

Comment: I wonder if the parent class has to be one created by Prototype's own system ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superclass argument needs to be a proper prototype "Class" - remember that classes don't really exist in JavaScript. There are several classical inheritance patterns for JavaScript and you should be able to get the prototype chain (including a reference to the parent "class" and it's prototype) by manually proxying constructors and prototypes around.

From [prototype's class.js](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/lang/class.js):

> [[Class.create]] accepts two kinds of arguments. If the first argument is
>   a [[Class]], it's used as the new class's superclass, and all its
>   methods are inherited. Otherwise, any arguments passed are treated as
>   objects, and their methods are copied over ("mixed in") as instance methods
>   of the new class.